# GeForce GTX 750 Ti Display Issue

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpgpu

[image]

[Perspective crop - original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg1DP.jpg ]

To resolve the above shown issue I have tried 3 different versions of drivers and also changed my desktop PC. But the problem is still there.

Initially the card was working fine. I need to perform General Purpose Computing (GPGPU) using this card.

1. 372.54-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql
2. 375.95-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql (clean installed this one)
3. 376.33-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql

System Configuration:

- Intel Core i5-4590
- RAM 4 GB
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
- Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Is there any possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the results for trying: New cable, different connection type (vga > hdmi > dvi), different monitor?

Comment: Please try to isolate the issue. If possible, try each 1) a different cable 2) a different port 3) a different gpu 4) a different monitor

Comment: Except different GPU, I have tried all the above mentioned solutions. I think I might have to send it back.